# SciFi Film / Anime in which somebody kills their romantic partner after mortal injuries

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, anime, the-outer-limits

I have this memory of a scene I have seen somewhere, and over the years have been completely unable to figure out where this is from.

There is a woman and man, who are romantically involved, and fight together in some sort of conflict (probably scifi-related). At some point near the end of the story the woman is mortally injured, at which point the man asks her to tell him again about the future she has envisioned for them both. A few seconds into her pained speaking he kills her.

If this exists I have seen this at some point between 1995 and 2012, possibly on TV in Germany. This could be a movie, anime, or a TV-show. It was probably not intended for children.

There is a chance this does not actually exist and my mind may have constructed this from various other scenes, as this does parallel some thing from Dune, and the mercy-kill shows up in other formats.

Could this be an Outer Limits episode? Those usually have a wide variety of stories in this vein.

Comment: Obligatory shout-out to "The Grapes of Wrath"